# NSStatusBar hidden in Mac OS X Lion

Tags: cocoa, fullscreen, osx-lion, nsstatusbar

I'm currently developing a status bar application. It's quite important to know if the status bar is hidden because an application entered the full screen mode. Is there a way to know that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much the only notification you're going to get is from [NSWorkspaceActiveSpaceDidChangeNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  Besides that, [NSRunningApplication](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html) might be of a little help but you can't immediately distinguish if an app is in fullscreen because (on the user-end), an app's fullscreen mode is handled entirely by the Dock app.